# Getting error in "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im getting the exception:

*Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed*

it says problem is in the method `teamNumberGet = rs.getInt("something");`

Where am I wrong?

code:

```java
try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

  String sql = "SELECT * FROM MatchScouting";
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


  for (int ayooo = 1; ayooo < indexReadFromDatabase; ayooo++) {
    rs.next();
  }
  ayo(rs, conn);
}
catch (SQLException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

public static void ayo(ResultSet rs, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
  int i = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
    i++;
    System.out.println("team---------------------------------" + i);

    teamNumberGet = rs.getInt("something");
  }          
}
```

I tried to find out if there was anywhere to make the ResultSet `rs` close, but it never did

Comment: for (int ayooo = 1; ayooo < indexReadFromDatabase; ayooo++) {
                     rs.next();
            } 
your code  will call rs.next indexReadFromDatabase -1 times  are you sure it's not loop more than the number of row from that resultset you get

Comment: better to use [try with resource](https://dev.java/learn/exceptions/catching-handling/#try-with-resources) so it auto close all the resource you do not need

Answer (score 0):

## Loop the result set once only

You went past the last row of your `ResulSet`, by looping twice on the same result set.

First you run your `for` loop (which you neglected to explain to us):

```
        for (int ayooo = 1; ayooo < indexReadFromDatabase; ayooo++) {
                 rs.next();
        }
```

Then you pass the ResultSet to the `mayo` method where you keep on calling [`ResultSet#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()). We don't know the value of `indexReadFromDatabase` but at some point your successive calls to `next` will move the cursor past the end of the result set.

Solution: **Loop the result set only once**.

Other issues:

- In modern Java, we need not call `Class.forName`. Many years ago JDBC was  changed to automatically load drivers via the [Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://Service%20provider%20interface) facility.
- You should be closing your JDBC resources when done with them. The [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax of Java 7+ makes this simple.

```java
try (
    Connection  conn = myDataSource.getConnection( myUrl , "" , "" ) ;
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; 
    ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery) ; 
)   
{
    while ( rs.next() ) { 
        … process results
    } 
} catch ( SqlException e ) {
    … handle exception
}
```